# nswag - provide custom json schema

Tags: nswag

Can I use nswag but providing my own json schemas for the data types? How do I do this, there are multiple files? I am also attempting to use embedded resources as the source from a shared library.
Using .net framework.

Tried using type-mapper but references kind of broke swagger gui
https://github.com/RicoSuter/NJsonSchema/wiki/Type-Mappers

```
settings.GeneratorSettings.TypeMappers.Add(new NJsonSchema.Generation.TypeMappers.ObjectTypeMapper(typeof(OutputRoot), OutputRootSchema));
```

If this is correct way, where can I read more about it & how to troubleshoot it.

Comment: What is OutputRootSchema?

Comment: A jsonschema e.g. embedded resource or from file.
Conceptually "Object type mapper"/second section in link.
But the general question is still - I have custom made schemas for the data, how can I make swagger use them.

Comment: I think you need to implement an own ITypeMapper (https://github.com/RicoSuter/NJsonSchema/blob/master/src/NJsonSchema/Generation/TypeMappers/ITypeMapper.cs) and then update the schema from the parameter with your JSON

Comment: Probably you’d add the custom schema to the schemas/components list and the type mapper returns a schema referencing the other one.

Comment: Is there any further information about how to trace & troubleshoot it.

Api samples just became
[
  {
    "ParametersRelative": "Unknown Type: array,null",

The models in swagger bottom breaks.

It's not something as stupid as I don't have examples in the hand made json schemas?